# Using Bitwise flags with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. My app uses razor in the views. My view has a checkbox list. The rendered HTML looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedValues" value="1" id="1" />
    <label for="1">Option 1</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedValues" value="2" id="2" />
    <label for="2">Option 2</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedValues" value="3" id="3" />
    <label for="3">Option 3</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedValues" value="4" id="4" />
    <label for="4">Option 4</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When a user clicks "Save", the values are stored in my model as a `int[] SelectedValues`.

My challenge is, my database only has a single field of type int. Can I do some sort of bitwise XOR on the `SelectedValues` and be safe? If so, how would I do that on the `SelectedValues` in C#?

Thank you!

Comment: The values would need to be 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes what you are asking is possible, the only issue is that because of the values you've picked performing an or will cause an conflict.

For example: `1 | 2 == 3` how would the code no that the option was supposed to be `1,2` or just `3`.

The solution is to convert this to bits. You can use the `<<` notation to do this. `<<` will shift a value to the left by a number of bits.

- `1<<0` gives you `1` or `00000001` as an 8 bit Binary
- `1<<1` gives you `1` or `00000010` as an 8 bit Binary
- `1<<2` gives you `1` or `00000100` as an 8 bit Binary
- `1<<3` gives you `1` or `00001000` as an 8 bit Binary
- `1<<4` gives you `1` or `00010000` as an 8 bit Binary

As you can see each item has a unique byte array and so you can then or them together to provide a combined result

- `1<<0 | 1<<2` gives you `5` or `00000101` in 8 bit binary

This is completely reversable.

- `(5 & 1<<2) != 0` will tell you if bit 2 is set or not.

To implement you can use Linq to convert your arrays.

To get a single integer from your array of ints:

```
var array = new[] {1,2,4};
var result = array.Aggregate(0, (x,y) => x | 1<<(y-1));
```

I've taken 1 away from each value so that an int of 1 becomes a value of 1

To reverse this you can again use linq to create an array.

```
var value = 5;
var result = Enumerable.Range(1,8).Select(x => (value & 1<<(x-1)) !=0).ToArray();
```

This will return an array of bools indicating true or false for each bit.

To get just a list of set values:

```
var value = 5;
var result = Enumerable.Range(1,8).Where(x => (value & 1<<(x-1))!=0).Select(x => 1 << (x-1)).ToArray();
```

This function works for 8 values but change it to suit.

Bear in mind that there is a maximum number of bits you can store in an integer, check the size for some its 16 bit integer for others it is 32 bit. c# as a language has 32bit integers, for bigger use a long.

Additionally you, shouldn't but, may run into issues using the top bit due to signed integers using the top bit for sign.

Answer (score 2):

For my sins, I have done this exercise.  I have stored data in a C# Flag Enum (which is a way of storing enums in a bitwise manner) and displayed in in a UI.

In your example case the enum would look something like

```
[Flags]
public enum SelectedValues
{
    [Display("Option 1")]
    Option1= 1,

    [Display("Option 2")]
    Option2= 2,

    [Display("Option 3")]
    Option3= 4,

    [Display("Option 4")]
    Option4= 8
}
```

in your example, your view model would have to have a member of type SelectedValues.

Then I used a display template to set a group of checkboxes.  I did it by creating a HTML helper for Flag Enums

```
public static class FlagEnumHelpers
{
    public static IHtmlString CheckBoxForFlagEnum<T>(this HtmlHelper<T> html, Enum item) 
    {

        TemplateInfo templateInfo = html.ViewData.TemplateInfo;
        string id = templateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(item.ToString());
        string name = templateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty);

        var checkbox = new TagBuilder("input");
        checkbox.Attributes["id"] = id;
        checkbox.Attributes["name"] = name;
        checkbox.Attributes["type"] = "checkbox";
        checkbox.Attributes["value"] = item.ToString();

        var model = html.ViewData.Model as Enum;

        if (model != null && model.HasFlag(item))
        {
            checkbox.Attributes["checked"] = "checked";
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(checkbox.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then created an Editor Template (in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates) which in your case be called SelectedValues.cshtml and would look like

```
  @model Your.Namespace.SelectedValues?
  <ul>
     <li>
     @Html.CheckBoxForFlagEnum(SelectedValues.Option1)
     </li>
     <li>
     @Html.CheckBoxForFlagEnum(SelectedValues.Option2)
     </li>
     <li>
     @Html.CheckBoxForFlagEnum(SelectedValues.Option3)
     </li>
     <li>
     @Html.CheckBoxForFlagEnum(SelectedValues.Option4)
     </li>
  </ul>
```

To be honest though I am not happy with it.  I think that MVC and Enums / bitwise operations don't play with each other very well.

Comment: Perhaps update this exelent answer for the new .net core package

Answer (score 1):

first things first your values are wrong, you need to use flags that relate to the bit being set, `1`, `2`, `4`, `8`, `16`...etc.

```
1 == 0001
2 == 0010
4 == 0100
8 == 1000
etc.
```

So

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedValues" value="1" id="1" />
    <label for="1">Option 1</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedValues" value="2" id="2" />
    <label for="2">Option 2</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedValues" value="4" id="3" />
    <label for="3">Option 3</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedValues" value="8" id="4" />
    <label for="4">Option 4</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You then simply add up your int's

```
int bitFlag = 0;
if (Model.SelectedValues !=null)
{
   foreach(int value in Model.SelectedValues)
        bitFlag += value;
}
```

Or using linq:

```
int bitFlag = 0;
if (Model.SelectedValues !=null)
     bitFlag = Model.SelectedValues.Sum(s => s);
```

So `1` and `4` being checked is `0101` or `5` as an integer

Comment: Thanks for the downvote on my (now deleted) answer. You could have quite easily allowed to me rectify/remove my answer without doing so. You are right that I was wrong, but IMO it detracts from the benefit of SO when people like yourself are too trigger happy on the downvotes.

Comment: I tried to help, without downvoting, but you couldn't see it. Your answer was wrong, so (eventually) I downvoted it. That's the way this site works, wrong answers get downvoted. It's not personal. If you'd simply corrected it, I would of removed my downvote.

Comment: I read the question wrong, I admit it - you were, no ARE right. you mentioned NOTHING about `int[]` in you original comment, you said "That not MVC its ASP.NET". I don't take it personally, but I do see value in my answer even if it's for someone else further down the line doing something SIMILAR. If the OP doesn't want it, don't mark it as the answer. Every answer on here tells him to use 1, 2, 4, 8 etc e.g. make a change. Why not make a change to use `bool[]` instead if `int[]`? Horses for courses.

Comment: all things being equal +1. Correct answer : )

Answer (score -1):

save as `Option 1 | Option 2 | Option 3 | Option 4`
but for this purpose your values must be `1 2 4 8 16 32 ...` and so on